# Setting up Less-Build in sublime text 2 - Mac OS X

Tags: less, sublimetext2

I've browsed and installed the following package

https://github.com/berfarah/LESS-build-sublime/blob/master/readme.md

I've created a file called style.less and inserted the following code (just to experiment)

```
@bgcolor: red;

body {
background: @bgcolor;
}
```

After saving the file and then hitting *command + b* to build the less file.

I'm expecting a style.css to be created when i hit *command + b*

Instead, i get a message on the console saying:

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory [cmd:  [u'lessc',
>   u'/Users/staff/Desktop/site/day2/css/style.less',
>   u'/Users/staff/Desktop/site/day2/css/style.css', u'--verbose']] [dir: 
>   /Users/staff/Desktop/`paperbusiness`/day2/css] [path:
>   /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
>   [Finished]

What could i be doing wrong?

Is there something i need to be doing in Packages/LESS-build/changeLESSBuildType.sh

It contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
PS3='Please enter your choice: '
options=("Normal" "Directory Rewrite" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "Normal")
            rm LESS.sublime-build
            ln -s LESS-normal.sublime-build-choice LESS.sublime-build
            break;
            ;;
        "Directory Rewrite")
            rm LESS.sublime-build
            ln -s LESS-rewriteDir.sublime-build-choice LESS.sublime-build
            break;
            ;;
        "Quit")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo invalid option;;
    esac
done
```

Thank you for reading this. Greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when I install LESS on MAC OS X Mountain Lion, I solved by installing LESS like this:

```
sudo npm install --global less
```

instead

```
npm install --global less
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to install node.js and npm first on your system to have sublime text build less into css.

download the installer from [nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org), run it. then open the terminal, enter the following:

```
npm install --global less
```

this installs the node.js package you need to build css files from less files. see [this tutorial](http://tech.diaslopes.com/?p=112) for more information. if this works, the build system in sublime text should work, too.

Comment: did exactly as instructed. Git this error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[cmd:  [u'lessc', u'/Users/kennethjaysone/Desktop/test.less', u'/Users/kennethjaysone/Desktop/test.css', u'--verbose']]
[dir:  /Users/kennethjaysone/Desktop]
[path: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
[Finished]